# For loop limit endless yet still working

Tags: java

I have been doing Java for a decently long time and I stumbled across this piece of code. I don't understand how it works:

```
int func(int num){
    int counter=0;
    for(int i=5;num/i>=1;i=i*5)
        counter=counter+num/i;
    return counter;
}
```

This function is a part of the program which counts the number of trailing zeros in a factorial. What I don't understand is the for loop part. The limit is usually the second condition and out here it is "`num/i>=1`".

I don't understand that if `i` take num as `100`, the limit would be `100/5 = 20`? But the part "`>=1`" is confusing me.

Comment: so 20 >= 1 so it loops

Comment: You haven't seen the `>=` operator before?  I can't imagine you've been working in Java for very long then...

Comment: Have you tried _executing_ it on paper? It can really help you undestand pieces of code like that.

Comment: This is a horrible piece of code, hard to read, inefficient...

Comment: i = 5 so 20 >= 1 loops again, i = 25 so 100/25 >= 1 or 4 >= 1 loops again, i = 125 so 100/125 >= 1 or 0 >= 1 (integer division) so it finishes after 2 iterations and the counter is 24 (20 for i = 5, 4 for i = 25)

Answer (score 3):

In the java `for` loop, there is no limit.  You might be thinking of BASIC.

In the java `for` loop, the 2nd expression is the *termination* expression.  The loop will keep looping for as long as the termination expression is `true`. 
 (That's why I prefer to think of it as the *continuation expression*, but never mind me.) Ofcourse, this expression must evaluate to a `boolean`.

`100/5` would be illegal as a termination expression, because it is of type `int`, not type `boolean`.

`100/5 >= 1` is a legal termination expression.  The loop will repeat for as long as `num/i` is larger than or equal to `1`.

More information about the java `for` loop:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html

Answer (score 2):

Your loop is equivalent (more or less) to this:

```
int func(int num){
  int counter=0;
  for(int i=5; i<=num;i=i*5)
    counter=counter+num/i;
  return counter;
 }
```

for a case where `num = 100`

the first iteration will be `i=5` and `num=100`

the second iteration will be `i=25` and `num=100`

the third iteration will be `i=125` and `num=100` in this case the loop exists because the condition (`num/i >= 1` [which is equivalent to] `i<=num`) is no longer fulfilled  (Edit: just in case `num/i = 0` in this case)

Answer (score 1):

This condition instructs the loop to continue until `num/i` becomes one or less. This is simply a boolean condition, which may be true or false. Once the condition becomes false, the loop stops.

Since `i` becomes five times greater than it has been during the prior iteration, the loop effectively divides by five to the power of `k+1`, where `k` is the number of iterations.

You can rewrite this by multiplying both sides by `i`:

```
for (int i=5 ; num >= i ; i=i*5) {
    counter += num/i;
}
```

Comment: Loved this answer! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

`num/i>=1` is, in fact, a condition.

Let's look at a few examples

```
num = 100; i = 5;
num/i >= 1; // true because 100/5 is greater than 1
num = 100; i = 200; 
num/i >= 1; // false because 100/200 is not greater than 1.
```

As you can see, num/i >= 20 is a condition that evaluates to true or false. The only tricky thing is that there is an expression (`num/i`) in the condition, rather than a single number.

Answer (score 0):

`num/i>=1` means your loop will be executed as long as this statement is true, so as long as the result of num divided by i ist greater

The thing is, that `i` is your loop variable, so it will grow everytime your loop is execute. So `num/i` will get smaller, until it is eventually smaller than 1.

Example: Num = 50

1. Loop: 50/5 >= 1? --> True
2. Loop: 50/25 >= 1? --> True
3. Loop: 50/ >= 1?25 --> False

At this point your Loop will stop.

Answer (score 0):

Ok let's take a simple example.
Here is the code:

```
public class Fact {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Fact().func(98);
    }

    int func(int num) {
        int counter = 0;
        for (int i = 5; num / i >= 1; i = i * 5) {
            System.out.println("num:  "+num + "/" + i + " = " + num / i);
            counter = counter + num / i;
            System.out.println("Counter = " + counter);
        }
        return counter;
    }
}
```

And here is the output for the example of 98.

```
run:
num:  98/5 = 19
Counter = 19
num:  98/25 = 3
Counter = 22
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

What happens is that: num/i is evaluated for the first loop step to 98/5 = 19.6 but it is **rounded** by java to 19 (it is integer).

Answer (score 0):

`num/i>=1` is a condition. How did you conclude 20 (100/5=20) will limit for the loop. denominator i is updated by the factor of i in each loop and check the condition. So for input num = 100 this how the loop will process

First

`for(i=5; 100/5>=1; i=25) condition is true`

Second

`for(i=25; 100/25>=1; i=125) condition is true`

In third iteration condition fails since 100/125 is not >=1.

100 has 2 zero and loop iterated 2 times.